# Rails active record object causes error when i try to access any attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, argument-error

I have code like:

```
@notifications = Notification.find_all_by_user_id(@user.id, :order=>'deliver_by DESC', :conditions=>"deliver_by >= '#{Date.today.to_s(:db)}'")
    logger.info @upcoming_reminders[0].inspect
    logger.info @upcoming_reminders[0].class
    logger.info @upcoming_reminders[0].id
    logger.info "--------------------------"
```

The logged result is

```
#<TwitterNotification id: 1, user_id: 3, message: "Testing", deliver_by: "2009-10-30 16:00:00", created_at: "2009-10-13 12:00:45", updated_at: "2009-10-28 20:01:03", processed_at: "2009-10-13 20:00:06", type: "TwitterNotification">
TwitterNotification

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):
  app/controllers/reminders_controller.rb:57:in `get_reminders'
```

As you can see, I get an argument error when trying to access the id.  This actually occurs when I try to access any attribute.  This may be a case of staring at the computer too long but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Any ideas?  Note that TwitterNotification is a subclass of Notification implemented using Single Table Inheritance.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I made a little progress, this works fine:

```
logger.info @upcoming_reminders[0][:id]
```

So accessing active record object attributes with a symbol works fine but dot notation does not.  Any idea why?

Comment: Where is the @upcoming_reminders array defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok not a case of staring at my computer too long.  I created a method called send in my model which does not seem to be allowed.

Comment: You actually overwrote Object#send (http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000332)